# How to get a page per register stored in DDBB in jasperreports?

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a report with the following structure:

**PAGE HEADER**

**DETAIL BAND (12 of those)**

**SUMMARY BAND**

The detail bands show depending on expressions I specified. Also, the content of the detail bands are subReports, one per detail band (don't know if that is relevant or not here).

What I'm trying to achieve is to execute the report without any filter as the ID or any other field of the table. Instead, I want to extract the information of all the registers of one specific table (let's name the table USER).

What I'm expecting to find when I execute the report is something like the following:

**PAGE HEADER**

**detail sections (shown depending on the expressions )**

**SUMMARY**

What I'm getting looks similar to the following:

**PAGE HEADER**

**DETAIL 1 (for user1)**

**DETAIL 2 (for user1)**

**DETAIL 1 (for user2)**

**DETAIL 4 (for user3)**

**and never the summary band (just at the end of the report)**

As you can see, all the users are getting mixed while what I want to do is to start a new page for each one of them.

QUESTIONS:

- How can I get the report to show each one of the users from the table
  in separate pages?
- Is there some property I missed that allows me to
  do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a way to solve this challenge. I just made a group (**Group1**) based on the ID's of the users and put the content of my Page Header inside the Group Header just created. Did the same with the Summary band, put all it contents inside the Group Footer.

Then, selecting the Group Header (or the Group Footer) I checked the **Keep Together** and the **Start New Page** checkboxs from the Appearance tab.

Furthermore, for each one of the detail bands, selected the **Group1** just created for the **Group Changes** selection combo in the Appearance tab.

I didn't do much testing yet but it seems like it's working as I wanted it to. If I find any other (better) solution I'll update the answer. Still open to hear advices though.